# javascript Miltiple tables and arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, bind

I want to write code for total of my tables data when user gives input and I have multiple tables with different IDs and having same classes. I want to make a total of inputs on keyup or when user enters the input. if anyone knows other method than this then please help me

````
                <thead>
                <th>Computed Amount</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="task_compute[]"  class="form-control calculate" autocomplete="off" class="form-group"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="task_compute1[]"  class="form-control calculate" autocomplete="off" class="form-group"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="task_compute2[]"  class="form-control calculate" autocomplete="off" class="form-group"  /></td>
      </tbody>
                <tfoot>
    <td style="padding-top:15px;" align="right"><b>TOTAL SALARY</b>
                </td><td>
                        <input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="sub_total[]" id="sub_total" value="" class="form-control"  class="form-group sub_total"  ></td></tfoot>
</table>

 <table id="example123" class="table example122 table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <th>Computed Amount</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="task_compute[]"  class="form-control calculate" autocomplete="off" class="form-group"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="task_compute1[]"  class="form-control calculate" autocomplete="off" class="form-group"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="task_compute2[]"  class="form-control calculate" autocomplete="off" class="form-group"  /></td>
      </tbody>
                <tfoot>
    <td style="padding-top:15px;" align="right"><b>TOTAL SALARY</b>
                </td><td>
                        <input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="sub_total[]" id="sub_total" value="" class="form-control"  class="form-group sub_total"  ></td></tfoot>
</table>```





//Js& Jquery

 ```$('.example122 > tbody > .calculate > input[type=text]:nth-child(1) ').on('input', '.calculate', function () {
        var id=$(this).parents('table').attr('id');
        calculateTotal(id);


});


    function calculateTotal(id) 
    {
        var grandTotal = 0;

                             $('#'+id+' > tbody > tr').each(function() {
            var c_sbt = $('.calculate', this).val();
                          grandTotal += parseFloat(c_sbt);
                          });

        var subT = parseFloat(grandTotal);


        $('.sub_total').val(subT.toFixed(2));
    }```




I am trying to run the above js and jquery but it is not working
````

Comment: What you mean by "_not working_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour? Alteast explain in details with example what you have inputted and where and what results you got or what didn't work.

Comment: It is giving input in table that time table is not getting print in the total text box
 below code is working when i have one table
  $('#example122').on('input', '.calculate', function () {
     calculateTotal();
 });
 function calculateTotal() 
 {
     var grandTotal = 0;
     $('#example122 tbody tr').each(function() {
                
            var c_sbt = $('.calculate', this).val();
                 grandTotal += parseFloat(c_sbt);
        });
     var subT = parseFloat(grandTotal);
      

     $('.sub_total').val(subT.toFixed(2));
 }

Comment: "_table is not getting print in the total text box_" how can anyone print a table inside a text box?

Comment: I mean to say the total value of the user's input is not getting print inside the textbox